# How do I build a Customized MinGW Cross Compiler with DW2

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I'm stuck in my work because of compatibility issues with libraries compiled with dw2 exception handling, where the MinGW Cross Compiler I use on Ubuntu has sjlj instead.

Its been a real pain trying to figure this out on my own. I somehow need to build a custom MinGW Cross Compiler I can use on Ubuntu that has dw2, instead of sjlj. Otherwise I will keep getting errors like: undefined reference to _unwind_resume. If anyone could possibly point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with MXE (MinGW Cross Environment)
http://mxe.cc/

MXE is built according to MinGW.org's (MinGW on Windows) instructions as far as I've tested (Meaning dw2). Mingw-w64 and the repos from most distros use sjlj too, so, that's a nope..

MXE's only "problem" is that it only builds static libs, but it includes quite a repertoire. It also may not be a problem.

Should that be unacceptable, http://mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW follow those steps. If the script fails due to a Function Name, go to line 130 in the .function file and comment those 3 lines about local

Comment: MXE is AWESOME and static libraries also are more convenient.